# Have trouble installing org mode (emacs)

Tags: emacs, windows-7, org-mode

I'm having trouble installing Org mode. I'm new to emacs and org mode. I've downloaded Org Mode from GNU site and extracted the zip file. However, I was unable to find .emacs file  to set the load-path which is (add-to-list 'load-path "~/path/to/orgdir/lisp").

Could anyone help me find this .emacs file? Cheers

Comment: If you have a fairly recent version of Emacs, it already has org-mode installed by default.  If you click on the save options inside the drop-down menu of the menu-bar, that should create a .emacs file in your home directory.  You may need to choose at least one option for that to occur, e.g., line wrapping or something else.  If you are not using a GUI version, you could create the .emacs file by hand -- it is just a flat text file that gets placed in your home directory.  Save options is also `M-x menu-bar-options-save`.

Comment: what version of Emacs do you use ? You certainly already have org-mode, and for a more up-to-date version, just apt-get install org-mode.

Comment: You can't "find this .emacs file", you have to create it: it's yours!

Comment: Ehvince: `apt-get install` not a useful suggestion for a question tagged with [windows-7].

Answer (score 1):

Emacs looks for the .emacs file in `$HOME` directory. To open the file, just do:

```
C-x C-f ~/.emacs
```

---

(If you are curious) to see where your home directory is, do the following:

1. Enter `M-x eshell`
2. Enter `echo $HOME`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to install emacs packages is to use the el-get package manager

https://github.com/dimitri/el-get

I use this for 80% of the packages I use daily.